# How to design a JQuery Calender to show only years using MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to design a calendar using JQuery where i can show only years in the calendar to select and read the value, where the month and day are not shown.Please see the picture to get a clear idea of what i mean. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try something like this

```
$( ".datefield" ).datepicker({
 changeMonth: false,
 changeYear: true,
 changeDat:false,
 yearRange:-90:+0
```

});